# Bootstrap 4 float-right not working with the navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

This is the code. I need to move navbar(without logo) to right side.

So I added float-right to like `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-right" id="navbarSupportedContent">`.

But it did not worked.

**Full Code**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Popular Quotes Collection</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse float-right" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Submit a Quote</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply add:

- `.justify-content-end` to `.navbar-collapse`
- Remove floats, bootstrap 4 is flexbox by default so you can take advantage of this.

Like this:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
```

**[Working Resizable Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yso6fqfd/9/)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can not use float because bs4 use display: flex; 
You can use class: 'justify-content-between' or get more about bootstrap4 flex class on this page https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to apply `float-right` at all, but rather `navbar-toggler-right`:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Popular Quotes Collection</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">Toggle</span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Submit a Quote</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it did not works because logo also goes to the right. Logo should be on left side and other munu's should go to the right

Comment: So the collapsible, drop-down menu should be the only one on the right?

Comment: Something like this. Please see the screenshot. https://image.ibb.co/hpVcdw/32323222222.png

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover that :)