# Bootstrap 4 navbar unable to shift items to the right

Tags: html, css

I am trying to shift my login and sign up buttons to the right of my navbar. I have tried using floats, ul containing it, align items and a ton more. Here is my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Connect4</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
      </li>

      <ul ul class="nav mr-auto" style="float: none!Important;">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
        </li> 
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign up</a>
        </li> 
      </ul>
      

    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597205/bootstrap-4-float-right-not-working-with-the-navbar) exact duplicate follow the first answer - that exactly what you need. Happy coding :)

Comment: @AlwaysHelping Hello, it does not. I am trying to only move 2 elements to the right atm

Comment: @Kamal thanks for clarifying ! See my answer all working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `justify-content-between` on your div `(navbar-collapse)` and put the `login` and `sign-up` ul outside the first `ul`

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="collapsibleNavbar">
```

**Demo:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Connect4</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add **ml-auto** in  tag
eg:

`<ul class="ml-auto"><ul>`

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap uses flexbox for it's nav, this is why `float`, `text-align` etc won't work. Instead, you will need to change your HTML structure to separate the inner `ul` with the buttons from the main `ul`, and then you can use the add the Bootstrap class `justify-content-between` to your navbar, e.g.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="collapsibleNavbar">
```

This tells the Bootstrap nav to align the 2 `ul` elements to either end of the nav bar- see the [Boostrap Flex documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#justify-content)

(Note, you can also remove the  `style="float: none!Important;"` inline style)

**Working Snippet:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
  <!-- Brand -->
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Connect4</a>

  <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <!-- Navbar links -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: This shifted all the elements to the right, is there a way to keep all to the left and to the right just login and sign up?

Comment: @Kamal I've updated my answer to work like this now.

Answer (score 1):

The Problem with your code was that you wrapped both `ul` inside one.Take 2 `ul` and apply `ml-auto` on one you want to push to the right.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">



<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md bg-dark navbar-dark">
      <!-- Brand -->
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Connect4</a>

      <!-- Toggler/collapsibe Button -->
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler"
        type="button"
        data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#collapsibleNavbar"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <!-- Navbar links -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
          </li>
        </ul>       
          
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sign Out</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        
      </div>
    </nav>
```